# How can i load an mp3 file to a react URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html

I've been trying to add a .mp3 file being loaded by Input on a URL, so i can play it using my player, but i cant load it as URL

I tried using FileReader with readAsDataURL, but i dont get URL for the file

I have this input

```
<input id="auInput" type="file" accept="audio/*" onChange={e => readURL(e)}/>
```

and the reader function:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if(input.target.files && input.target.files[0]){
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(e){
            let audio = new Audio(e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.target.files[0]);
// This is where i need the URL to add it to player:
        sourceAux = reader.result;

}
```

I expect a URL and im just getting an empty string

Comment: JavaScript is async. The loading hasn’t happened yet. In the callback you’re setting it probably is set

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer, by using this

```
function readURL(input){
        sourceAux = URL.createObjectURL(input.target.fles[0]);
        console.log(sourceAux);
        let audio = new Audio(sourceAux);
}
```